# Can the default tvOS controller support also be used for the iOS and macOS version of an app/game?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, tvos

I developed a small game for iOS, macOS and tvOS and just discovered that the tvOS version automatically supports for example the DualShock controller as it basically just uses the same inputs as on the Siri remote. (Moving left/right/up/down and pressing a button for selection) It's already pretty nice that this works just out of the box, but I was wondering, if this behaviour can also be mapped to the iOS/macOS version? Something like GCController -> Use the navigation of tvOS's focus engine.